# Execute a jar from an application but use the same printwriter

Tags: java, jar

Hi I'm currently working on a little commandline program which should be able to update itself. My solution for the update process is to run an updater (another jar file) which downloads a new jar, replacing it with the old one and executing it. Everything is working fine except when starting the updater or the downloaded jar there are no outputs visible on the terminal.

To run a jar I use ProcessBuilder:

```
...
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", JAR_FILE);
Process ps = builder.start();
ps.waitFor();
...
```

Is it possible to use the same PrintWriter or something else to see the outputs from the executed jars?

**Edit:**
The main problem is when for example the updater is called the main process terminates itself so it is safe to replace the jar file from the main process and start it again.

Comment: check spring dynamic modules / OSGI framework

Comment: Would it be possible to load the class at runtime instead of creating a new process?  It would probably involve writing a `ClassLoader`, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: `Process` class has a [`#getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) method, you can wrap it into a `BufferedInputStream` or `Scanner` and use it as usual. It will read the output of the other process.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to load the class at runtime because I want to replace the jar that is currently executed. I somewhere read that replacing the jar that is executed can lead to behaviour that is is not offically defined..

Comment: Deleted my answer after I realized what I had been doing was dumb. You can get the same effect by just running builder.inheritIO()  before the builder.start(). Unfortunately as far as I can tell if the process that calls builder.start() exits so does the subprocess.

Comment: and that is exactly my problem... I think the best and only solution for this problem will be spring dynamic modules although I have never worked with the Spring framework